# How to show missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2017

I have two tables like below in SQL Server 2017:

**Table X**

```
XID Name
1  A
1  B
1  C
2  A
2  B 
3  C
```

**Table Y**

```
YID Name
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

I want to show the missing [Y].[Name] for each X data.

**Expected output**

```
XID Name
1   D
2   C
2   D
3   A
3   B
3   D
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a bit clunky, but you could cross join the two tables, and then subtract an equijoin from them:

```sql
SELECT     x.id, y.name
FROM       x
CROSS JOIN y
EXCEPT
SELECT     x.id, y.name
FROM       x
JOIN       y ON x.name = y.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `cross join` the list of `name`s with the list of (distinct) `xid`s and then filter on missing entries with `not exists`:

```
select x.xid, y.name
from y
cross join (select disctinct xid from x) x
where not exists (select 1 from x x1 where x1.id = x.id and x1.name = y.name)
```